# how to read .evtx files?

Tags: perl, winapi, event-log

I would like to read the contents of the Event Log on Windows using the Perl script. I can read the contents of the 'Application' Log. I can't read old logs - .evtx files. Can you advise me where I have a mistake?

```
$filename = "C:/Windows/System32/winevt/Logs/Archive-Application-2022-10-26-16-18-53-831.evtx";
if (-f $filename) {
    printf "%s ... continue ...\n", $filename;
} else {
    printf "PROBLEM\n";
    exit -1;
}
$EventLog = new Win32::EventLog($filename) || die $!;
$EventLog->GetOldest($first) || die $!;    # it dies here
```

EDIT:

Function `GetOldest` returns a `RecordNumber`. I tried UNC:

```
$filename = "\\\\<server>\\C\$\\Windows\\System32\\winevt\\Logs\\Archive-Application-2022-10-25-04-01-56-731.evtx";
```

... but the same error. The file exists but died on the GetOldest function. I haven't found something like `$EventLog->errstr` anywhere on the internet ...
https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::EventLog

Comment: One of your mistakes is not revealing the error messages. Assuming `$!` is applicable here, there might be a module specific error handling, like `$EventLog->errstr`. Is `GetOldest` a function that returns a non-negative value on success?

Comment: New users are expected to take the [tour]. It's also highly recommended to read through [ask].

Comment: If the function returns a number, and that number is `0` that will trigger the `die` statement. Perhaps using die there is not optimal. Or you could do `die "No oldest records found!"`.

Comment: @Jiri, Re "*The file exists but died on the GetOldest function*" `GetOldest` is a wrapper for the `GetOldestEventLogRecord` system call. Like pretty much every other system call, the error that causes `GetOldestEventLogRecord` to fail can be obtain from the `GetLastError` system call. This is available in Perl as `$^E`. What error do you get?

Comment: @TLP, It returns true on success or false on error. The number is "returned" via an output parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a powerful thing: I canceled the error test:
originally : #$EventLog->GetOldest($first) || die $!;
now : $EventLog->GetOldest($first);
... and continue with the script; the script reads the contents of the .evtx file correctly.